# Translate the Wordpress Comment function into multiple languages

Tags: wordpress, translation, translate, multiple-languages

I usually work with Typo3 and I am not an experienced player with wordpress.

**Initiation:** 
It's a matter of a website for partially sighted people (http://www.tactuel.ch).  
The Website was created with Wordpress.

With an click on the top right the user can switch between german and french.

**Problem:**
On many subsites of this website you can find a commentform like here: (http://www.tactuel.ch/fr/bonjour/le-contenu-de-tactuel/) This is the French version of the Website.

The commentform is grey and has the Id "comments".

In the grey box there are two little "form-boxes" which you can select:

1.) "Benachrichtige mich über nachfolgende Kommentare via E-Mail." 
2.) "Benachrichtige mich über neue Beiträge via E-Mail."

**The hole commentform-box was automatically translated to French except those two texts next to the "form-boxes"**

In the Backend I didn't find any Plugin for this commentform which could be configurated.

Do you know how I can translate these two texts?

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look in your theme folder and search in :

- Comments template (for example `comments.php` in twentytwelve theme) : search for a call to [`comment_form()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form) function,
- and eventually in `functions.php` (since it is possible to modify comment form using filters).